# With Winget command, how do you list only upgradeable apps

Tags: winget

There doesn't seem to be a built in option to filter by available upgrade or source.

I have tried this but it still lists everything:

```
winget list --source winget
```

Comment: Some kind of `appget outdated`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I found a solution that works. You use the `upgrade` command with no arguments instead of the `list` command. This wasn't clear to me in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade) but works perfectly.

```
winget upgrade
```

Comment: FYI, the documentation has been clarified: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade#using-upgrade

Comment: And if you want to do actual upgrade of all those packages type `winget upgrade --all`

Answer (score 7):

You can also filter by source using this syntax

```bash
winget list --upgrade-available --source=winget
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Running the command `winget upgrade` to get available upgrade
Fromthe response if you want to upgrade any then type in `winget upgrade <id name>`